# SQL query for user presence

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm not sure how to write Postgres view that will select correct records.
I have two tables:

**user_tab**

```
user_id
email
```

and

**absence_tab**

```
absence_id
user_id
date_from
date_to
```

in absence_tab represents date range when user is not available (in work ;) ).
I would like to list all users that are available on some date, so they aren't presents in absence_tab in that date.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Output from this query will be users that don't exist in `absence_tab` in `2016-08-29` meaning that they are, as you have said, available in that day.

```
select *
from user_tab u
where not exists (
  select 1
  from absence_tab a
  where u.user_id = a.user_id
    and '2016-08-29' between date_from and date_to
  )
```

Comment: Well, that query will work, but I would like to create view for that. So AFAIK if I would like to pass date as query argument (WHERE) then columns `absence_from` and `absence_to` should be selected also ;). Any idea?

Comment: You could use a set returning function instead of creating a view. A view would require totally different code and I'm afraid would not be as efficient, since it would require more data processing.